# Style resource with datatrigger accessing per element value

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, styles, datatrigger

I have this construct in my xaml.

```
<Type1 visibility={binding bool1, converter=BoolToVisibilityConverter}/>
<Type1 visibility={binding bool2, converter=BoolToVisibilityConverter}/>
<Type1 visibility={binding bool3, converter=BoolToVisibilityConverter}/>
<Type1 visibility={binding bool4, converter=BoolToVisibilityConverter}/>
```

However, the users want to see the items where the bool values are false, but in a disabled state. Therefore, I want the bool1, bool2 etc to feed datatriggers in a style.

However, the "bool1", "bool2" texts are explicit today per element of Type1 (they are binding to the viewmodel. Type1 also has other bindings to the viewmodel, so I do not wish to make it a listview or anything changing the datacontext per element.

How do I make a **style resource** whose datatrigger (or any trigger) can access bound values that are **defined per element**? Do I bind locally per element against some placeholder element attribute and then use element triggers in the style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the bools should actually have nothing to do with the Visibility, why don't you bind directly to `IsEnabled`? And if you want to bind to values on the object you can use a [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource.aspx) binding with `Mode=Self`.

Comment: The elements in question are expander elements. Even though they shall have an inactive "feel" to them, I do not know that the expand function itself should be disabled. 
Yes, the RelativeSource with Mode=Self is what I was thinking of when suggesting a "placeholder" value that would in turn be accessed by an element trigger in the style. But is there any dependency property that is suited for this? "IsEnabled" would impact the functionality of the control, in a way which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: @Tormod: You can use the Tag as a placeholder if you do not use that for anything else already, or you could create an [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx)